# Como receber valores no formato date de uma base de dados Sybase?

Tags: php, odbc, sybase

Boas, preciso de ir buscar a uma base de dados Sybase campos do tipo Date para preencher na minha aplicação.

Ao ir buscar a informação necessária e ao fazer um debug da mesma, os campos no formato Date aparecessem-me vazios em vez de estarem preenchidos com o seu respectivo valor na base de dados.

Estou a utilizar ODBC para fazer a ligação à base de dados.

Alguem sabe o porquê disto acontecer?

A minha query no model é muito simples:

```
public function recibo($codigo, $numero) {
    require(APPPATH . 'libraries/odbc_conn.php');
    $query = odbc_exec($db, "select * from GP_Web_Recibos where Codigo = 14 AND Numero = 3302");
    while ($row = odbc_fetch_array($query)) {
        $tudo[] = $row;
    }

    if (empty($tudo)) {
        $tudo = 0;
    }

    return $tudo;
}
```

Controller :

```
public function teste2() {
    $nrrecibo = $this->uri->segment(3);
    $codigo = $this->session->codigo;
    $campos = $this->Vencimentos_model->recibo($codigo, $nrrecibo);
    $abono = [];
    $descontos = [];
    foreach ($campos as $key => $campo) {
        if ($campo['Codigo_Paga_Desc'] == '1') {
            $abono[] = $campo['Resultado'];
        } elseif ($campo['Codigo_Paga_Desc'] == '2') {
            $descontos[] = $campo['Resultado'];
        }
        # code...
    }

    $campos['abonototal'] = array_sum($abono);
    $campos['descontostotal'] = array_sum($descontos) - $campos[0]['Vl_SSOC'] - $campos[0]['Vl_IRS'];
    $data['campos'] = $campos;
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($campos);
    echo "</pre>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a new field with the value of each field i want with the converted value of it.

```
$query = odbc_exec($db, "select *, CONVERT(Varchar(50), Data, 1) as DATA  from GP_Web_Recibos where Codigo = 14 AND Numero = 3302");
```